# Change the post thumbnail lcoation

Tags: wordpress

I just want to ask a simple question. How to make the featured images that placed above the title to disappear and place it right below the post title? What filter do I need? The only thing that I want to know is how to make the title disappear because I need it for my plugin. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you will need to edit the appropriate page. If you want this change to be on the individual pages then you will need to make the change in the single.php file. Simply move the code that references the thumbnail to below the title tag:

ABOVE THE TITLE

`<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
    the_post_thumbnail();
} 
?>
<?php the_title(); ?>`

BELOW THE TITLE

`<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
    the_post_thumbnail();
} 
?>`

If it's on a different page:

- page.php for individual pages
- single.php for individual pages
- archive.php for archive pages
- index.php for main blog page

Comment: It's for plugin, not theme development. What I need is to let the user have the option either they want to get the post thumbnail on top of the title, or  below without having to config their theme files, what I really need is the name of the filter :)